# Where's the bounty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounty

[This](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/where-to-begin-finding-estimates-for-problems-with-potential-first-home/1587#1587) question had a 50 point bounty on it, and my answer was accepted but I did not receive the 50 points.

The asker lost 50 points, so where's the bounty?  Is this a glitch in the system, or did [justkt](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/683/justkt) lose 50 points for nothing?

Comment: Interesting - it said +50 when I awarded it to you, and now - nothing.  I'm sorry - I thought your answer was worth it!

Comment: @justkt: no worries.  I just don't understand why you have to throw points into the abyss.  If nobody gets the bounty do to some strange rules or something, you should keep the bounty.

Comment: then everyone would just start bounties all the time, since there is no risk whatsoever.. it'd be like marking all outgoing email IMPORTANT!!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I'm just saying if no answers meet the criteria for the bounty, the bounty should be refunded.  If an answer is accepted the bounty should be given to the poster of that answer.  If I really needed an answer and set a bounty, why should I lose rep if nobody can answer the question?  It just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

Bounties are no longer tied to answer acceptance. It could be that the OP didn't realise this and let the bounty expire. If no answer meets the auto acceptance criteria (answer posted **after** the bounty was started and has a score of at least +2) then the bounty is lost.

Also anyone can set a bounty on any question - not just their own.

Comment: So if no bounty is awarded, why does the bounty starter lose rep?  It just doesn't seem right.

Comment: I totally didn't realize that - that's what the +50 thing was, I guess.  Darnit, meant to award!

Comment: @Tester101 - it's always been thus. As soon as you set a bounty you lose the rep and it's non refundable.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Check out this question on meta.stackoverflow.com: [Bounty not awarded even though question answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/bounty-not-awarded-even-though-question-answered)</strike>

I think the answer was not accepted in the bounty time frame.  The bounty was created on 2010-09-02 02:50:57 and the answer accepted on 2010-09-09 12:05:46 so that is over the 7 days.

See @ChrisF's answer.

Comment: Although it would be good if someone with more knowledge of the bounty system could confirm this is the reason why.

Comment: See my answer.