# Bug in bounty system? +100 bounty from a rep 65 member

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounty

So a reputation 65 member put a +100 bounty on this question:
[Why does cold water always mix in bathtub mixing valve, even on hottest setting?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38091/why-does-cold-water-always-mix-in-bathtub-mixing-valve-even-on-hottest-setting/38677#38677)

I thought it odd, but whatever. Should it have been possible to set that level of bounty, and what happened to the bounty in the end?  Can bounty draw from other SE sites, and if so which one?

See also [Where's the bounty](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/wheres-the-bounty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [other answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/928/22), the OP had over 160 rep at the time he created the bounty, so a 100 rep bounty was within the rules.

See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/146318) on [Meta Stack Overflow] for more than you ever wanted to know about bounties.

In this case, the bounty expired about 7 hours ago as I write this. The person who created the bounty has a 24 hour grace period to award the bounty; if they don't, the Community user awards 50 % of the bounty according to the rules from the FAQ:

> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

<s>It looks like yours was the only answer started after the bounty, and you have the +2 score, so (unless the OP decides on the other answer) you should be seeing the bounty in about 17 hours.</s>

While yours was the only answer started after the bounty, you only had one upvote during the bounty period, so the bounty wasn't awarded.

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect to say that a 65 rep user set a 100 rep bounty... a 165 rep user set a 100 rep bounty hence he became a 65 rep user :-)

See the rep timeline here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/15889/greg-smalter?tab=reputation&sort=time